# React Native on iOS - "Unhandled JS exception: Can't find variable: require"

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I was able to build the project without errors, but when I launched my React Native app on iOS I got the following error:

[image: Image of error code]

> Error Code: Unhandled JS Exception: Can't find variable: require`

It was working fine, but when I was debugging something else I ended up removing the pods folder, podfile.lock, and .xcworkspace directory and running:

```
pod deintegrate
pod install
```

I am not sure exactly why the error is popping up. How can I fix it?

I tried to reset the cache too, but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting your cache:

On expo

```
expo r -c
```

For React Native CLI:

```
react-native start --reset-cache
```

Comment: yea I tried that already.  Also tried cleaning the project.

Comment: Also, i tried to revert back to an old commit, but I received the same error

Answer (score 0):

After reverting back a bunch more commits I realized I had added '@babel/preset-env' as a preset in my babel.config.js file.  After removing that the error went away.